# Connecting slider to view - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am using this library to include a range slider in my swift app: https://github.com/TomThorpe/TTRangeSlider

I added a view, and set the class to TTRangeSlider

The slider works. But, I need to retrieve the selectedMinimum and selectedMaximum

When I try to drag the view from the storyboard to the controller to create an outlet, I get the error: `Use of undeclared type TTRangeSlider`

How do I access these values without having the add the slider programmatically??

Here is what I have in my view controller:

```
@IBOutlet var rangeSlider: TTRangeSlider!
```

I included all the necessary library files. And here is what I have in my bridging header:

```
#import "TTRangeSlider.h"
```

Comment: Please add some sample code so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Can you zip your project and upload it to Dropbox or Google Drive and I´ll take a look at it.

Comment: @john_ryan I updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @RashwanL I updated my answer. Is there a better library I can user that will allow me to add a range slider in the story board instead of programmatically?

Comment: Can you please check on storyboard in the **Connections Inspector** (cmd + opt + 6) that the `rangeSlider` outlet appears on your view controller? If yes, can you try to drag from this tab to the view on the canvas?